pyspark convert comma seperated string into dataframe
I have string like below
Gourav , Joshi ,"Karnataka, India" ,,"gouravj09@hotmail,gouravj09@gmail.com"
Is there any way to convert this into dataframe in spark where each comma considered as new column
Final DataFrame should look like this

note - this string generated within loop and during each loop new string gets generated , I have to append this string into dataframe after splitting that with comma seperator

Does spark.read.csv not work ? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html

This string present within variable, during each loop new string gets generated and need to append this into dataframe.

are you looking to create a new dataframe based on this field or expand this one column into 5 columns on the existing dataframe?

Create new dataframe

Usually you want to read data from a file with spark, even from a set of files to support parallel processing. As already suggested in comments spark.read.csv is what you should use to read csv file.
I added examples with temporary file, just to give you an inline working example. For real cases I recommend writing a real file.
You can provide a schema into the csv function or include a header into your file. If no schema is provided, spark will name columns _cN.
import tempfile

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as fp:
    fp.write(b"""Gourav , Joshi ,"Karnataka, India" ,,"gouravj09@hotmail,gouravj09@gmail.com" \n""")
    fp.close()

    spark.read.csv(fp.name).show()

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as fp:
    fp.write(b"""Gourav , Joshi ,"Karnataka, India" ,,"gouravj09@hotmail,gouravj09@gmail.com" \n""")
    fp.close()

    spark.read.csv(fp.name, schema="Name string, Surname string, Address string, Phone string, Email string").show()

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as fp:
    fp.write(b"""Name,Surname,Address,Phone,Email\n""")
    fp.write(b"""Gourav , Joshi ,"Karnataka, India" ,,"gouravj09@hotmail,gouravj09@gmail.com" \n""")
    fp.close()

    spark.read.csv(fp.name, header=True).show()

+-------+-------+----------------+----+--------------------+
|    _c0|    _c1|             _c2| _c3|                 _c4|
+-------+-------+----------------+----+--------------------+
|Gourav | Joshi |Karnataka, India|NULL|gouravj09@hotmail...|
+-------+-------+----------------+----+--------------------+

+-------+-------+----------------+-----+--------------------+
|   Name|Surname|         Address|Phone|               Email|
+-------+-------+----------------+-----+--------------------+
|Gourav | Joshi |Karnataka, India| NULL|gouravj09@hotmail...|
+-------+-------+----------------+-----+--------------------+

+-------+-------+----------------+-----+--------------------+
|   Name|Surname|         Address|Phone|               Email|
+-------+-------+----------------+-----+--------------------+
|Gourav | Joshi |Karnataka, India| NULL|gouravj09@hotmail...|
+-------+-------+----------------+-----+--------------------+

